# Set initial state using apollo client

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, graphql-js

I am trying to set the intial state of a react state variable using the prop created using the apollo client with graphql.

```
 this.state = {data:myFunc(this.props.data};
```

The problem is that this.props.data is empty when the state is set. I looked at setting in the lifecycle methods, but it still returns empty. It is only when a function is called within render() that I get the output.

Comment: how your component looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `this.props.data` is loaded asynchronously and is not yet loaded when you attempt to assign it to `this.state` (I assume in the constructor).

A good place to do it would be in `getDerivedStateFromProps`:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, prevState) {
  if (props.data && !prevState.data) {
    // Only return this when props.data has just loaded. 
    // Figure out the best way to determine that for your code.
    return { data:  myFunc(props.data) };
  }
  return {};
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

Comment: Yes, the apollo client does load the data asynchronously and yes the state is set in the constructor. There is a "loading" attribute supplied to results, but even after checking for this     if (!props.data.loading) ... the result is still empty.

Comment: My mistake, I had not removed the initial state call. This works fine now. Thanks.